# Error when converting Image to Byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to convert Image to **Byte[]**  :

```
byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("user-defolt.png");
```

But I had following error :

[image]

Comment: Where is that file located? The error couldn't be much clearer than that.

Comment: This is the most trivial question I have seen on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use physical path:

```
byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\user-defolt.png");
```

or

```
byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes( Server.MapPath("user-defolt.png"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the full path of the file you want to read, other wise it looks for the file in the directory, in which your executable  is located.

```
    byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Desktop\file.png") // Some arbitary path.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out.**

```
    public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); //Save any type of format you want, like jpeg, png,gif etc
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you look to exception, have a problem with file path.

Make `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\some_folder\"`
This mean, get all files in "some_filder"

Hope this help!